# Custom Overlay with UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum

Tags: ios, overlay, uiimagepickercontroller

I need to let the user select a photo from the Photo Library and be able to size and crop their image while using an Overlay image. Using `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` with `cameraOverlayView` is fine, but `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum` does not support that property.

Strangely enough, when I add the overlay view as a subView with alpha set at half, the overlay appears on the Photo selection screen, but this wont fly with Apple's approval process.

```
-(void)choosePhotoDialog:(id)sender
{ 
    UIBarButtonItem * barThing = (UIBarButtonItem*)sender;

    OverlayView * overlay = [[OverlayView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH_IPHONE, SCREEN_HEIGTH_IPHONE)
                                               andPhotoOverlay: [dict objectForKey:@"imageUrl"]];
    [overlay setUserInteractionEnabled: NO];

    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    switch (barThing.tag) 
    {
        case 0: [picker setSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
                [picker setShowsCameraControls: YES];  
                [picker setCameraOverlayView: overlay];
            break;
        case 1: [picker setSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];
                [picker.view addSubview: overlay];
                [overlay setAlpha: 0.5f];
            break;
    }

    [picker setDelegate: self];
    [picker setAllowsEditing: YES];
    [picker setNavigationBarHidden: YES];
    [picker setWantsFullScreenLayout: YES];
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];  
    [picker release];
}
```

### Question

**What is the correct way to allow a user to select a photo from the PhotoLibrary with an Overlay using `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum`?**

[image: Overlay on Thumbs]  [image: Overlay on Photo]

---

### Resolved

Basically, I needed to write 3 separate classes and combine them to create my own custom photo editing view, which also saves pinch / zoom / rotate edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing several classes:

1. An **`OverlayView`** class which is a `UIView` and simply retrieves the .png image with transparency and is the bottom-most layer.
2. An **`InteractiveWallpaper`** class which is a `UIImageView` and handles all of the `touch` events, including the transformation events.
3. And finally, an **`EditingView`** class which is a `UIViewController`. This adds the 2 views previously mentioned as well as saves the photo that the user edited.

This also allowed me to customize the behavior of the view. When the user touches the imported photo, the top-most photo decreases it's alpha value, allowing the user to still see the overlay while the imported photo is more visible.